# Does Instagram support Oauth 2.0 and CRUD management over REST API?

Tags: oauth-2.0, instagram-api

I have searched a lot these days trying to understand the recent changes happening to the Instagram API. I had in mind that there is some sort of an API that allows you to manage your account (posts/followers etc.) using an application other than the official mobile and web apps (connected via Oauth 2.0). Is there such a capability?

Comment: Try: https://www.instagram.com/developer/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have, but the thing is that the Instagram API has been deprecated since October and now almost none of its features work.